# How can I make this more concise?

Tags: c#, linq

```
var users = from user in st.Users
            where user.UDID == cr.User.Udid
            select user;
var cityIds from city in users.First().Cities
            select city.ID;
DoSomethingWith(cityIds);
```

It started as this query:

`select CityID from UserCities inner join User on User.ID=UserID where User.UDID=@UDID;`

I can't seem to get the join syntax right with Linq-to-Entities

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using query expressions isn't really helping you here, and you wouldn't need two of them anywehere. Here's a direct translation:

```
var cityIds = st.Users
                .Where(user => user.UDID == cr.User.Udid)
                .First()
                .Cities
                .Select(city => city.ID);
```

Now use the fact that [`First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302744.aspx) can take a predicate, and you can remove the `Where`:

```
var cityIds = st.Users
                .First(user => user.UDID == cr.User.Udid)
                .Cities
                .Select(city => city.ID);
```

Comment: Sorry, why is using query expressions not helping? When to use them?

Comment: @manojlds: It's introducing more cruft than it's removing. When you've *only* got a select clause or *only* got a where clause and a trivial select, you end up with no benefit. Why use `from x in collection select x.y` rather than `collection.Select(x => x.y)`? Developers need to be confident in both approaches, IMO.

Comment: Note also that if I have to mix in calls which aren't supported by query expressions such as `First`, as part of the logical flow (rather than an inner expression such as a condition) I'd generally rather go to dot notation to start with. I think the code I've given above is nice and clear in terms of the flow - it moves from all users to one user to the cities to the city ID. The logical flow is the same as the order of the code.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what I wanted to achieve.

```
var cityIds = from city in st.Users.First(x => x.UDID == cr.User.Udid).Cities
              select city.ID
```